# How to get next 12:00:00PM in javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date

Just need to know how to get the closest 12:00:00pm in the JavaScript date object, for some reason I'm baffled! EG if it is 09:00AM on the 1st of July, then it will be 12:00PM 1st July, however if it's 01:00PM on the 1st of July, then I need 12:00PM 2nd July returning.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this: Add a day if hours > 12

```js
var nextNoon = new Date();
if (nextNoon.getHours() >= 12) nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate() + 1)
nextNoon.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0)
console.log(nextNoon)
```

Answer (score 3):

try this ...

```
var dt = new Date();
var tomorrowNoon = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + 1, 12, 0, 0);
```

I've checked it out for going past the end of the month and that works too ...

```
var dt = new Date(2011, 7, 31);
var tomorrowNoon = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + 1, 12, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry Antony, I changed the goalposts as you were posting this! Thanks anyways for the answer, this gets tomorrows 12 regardless.

Comment: He wanted next noon, i.e. noon today if now is before noon

Comment: When I originally posted the question I said I needed tomorrows noon in the date object.. It was my bad, in fact I needed the next noon (so if it was 9AM today, next noon would be 12PM today, if it was 1PM today, next noon would be 12AM tomorrow).

Comment: FYI there's a bug in the first section of this answer.  dt.getDay() should say dt.getDate() like it does in the 2nd section.  So it should read something like: `var dt = new Date(); return new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + 1, 12, 0, 0);` And yes, as the previous commenter noticed, this gives tomorrow's noon, not the next noon. But that worked for me, since that is what I wanted for my project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's Date is lenient in the sense that e.g. Aug 32 equals Sep 1, so something like this perhaps:

```
function getNextNoon() {
  var noon = new Date();
  if (noon.getHours() >= 12) {
    noon.setDate(noon.getDate() + 1);
  }
  noon.setHours(12);
  noon.setMinutes(0);
  return noon;
}
```

Comment: Thanks gustav, same method as mplungan, works great but yep too many setMinutes, thanks for the answer